# Consultar tablas diferentes por campo fecha

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo tres tablas registros cotizaciones y órdenes. Aunque están relacionadas entre si, quisiera consultar no por ID sino por su campo fecha. cotizaciones (feccotizacion) registros(fecregistro) órdenes ( fecorden). Cómo podría hacer un join por los campos fechas para poder traer una consulta mensual. Gracias.

Quisiera la consulta en crudo Mysql.

Tengo esta consulta pero los valores de ingresos (tabla registros) no son los correctos. No sé que tengo mal en la consulta.

```
SELECT MONTH(c.feccotizacion) as mes, ies.ingresos, SUM(c.totalcotizacion) AS totalcotizacion
FROM cotizaciones AS c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT r.fecregistro
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos
                    FROM registros AS r 
                      WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) 
                        AND r.idestado <> 7                             
                    GROUP BY month(r.fecregistro)
                  ) ies
           ON ies.fecregistro = c.feccotizacion                  
WHERE c.id_estado <> 7 AND c.feccotizacion BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15'
GROUP BY MONTH(c.feccotizacion) DESC
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tus modelos, el resultado deseado y lo que has tratado

Comment: Estoy trabajando primero con Mysql crudo. Por el momento tengo está consulta que me trae bien los totales de cotizaciones pero los valores de ingresos(tabla registros) no son los reales. La consulta es: